# camera calibration with open cv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to calibrate a stereo camera, and I have written some code to store the parameters in an XML file so that I can use them in other codes. The problem is that when I do this, an empty XML file is generated. When I print the data, it shows the parameters in the terminal, but it simply doesn't save them to the file. How could I make sure they are saved?

[when i print 'data'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geeIt.png)

The error that comes right after that:

File "c:\Users\Camila\Documents\stereo-vision\calibration\calibration_two.py", line 109, in 
cv_file.write('stereomap', data)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'write'

> Overload resolution failed:
>
> - Argument 'val' is required to be an integer
> - Argument 'val' can not be treated as a double
> - Can't convert object to 'str' for 'val'
> - val is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
> - Can't parse 'val'. Input argument doesn't provide sequence protocol

```
    import cv2 as cv
    import glob
    
    #####find chessboard corners - objecr points and image points
    
    chessboardSize = (8,6)
    frameSize = (480, 640)
    
    #termination criteria
    
    criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
    
    
    #prepare objetcs points
    
    objp = np.zeros((chessboardSize[0] * chessboardSize[1], 3), np.float32)
    objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:chessboardSize[0],0:chessboardSize[1]].T.reshape(-1,2)
    
    objp = objp * 24
    print(objp)
    
    # arrays to store object points and image points from all the images
    
    objpoints = [] #3d point in the real world space
    imgpointsL = [] # 2d points in image plane
    imgpointsR = [] #2d points in image plane
    
    imagesLeft = glob.glob('calibration/camera1/*.jpg')
    # print(imagesLeft)
    imagesRight = glob.glob('calibration/camera0/*.jpg')
    
    
    for imgLeft, imgRight in zip(imagesLeft, imagesRight):
        imgL = cv.imread(imgLeft)
        imgR = cv.imread(imgRight)
        grayL = cv.cvtColor(imgL, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        grayR = cv.cvtColor(imgR, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
        #find the chessboard corners
        retL, cornersL = cv.findChessboardCorners(grayL, chessboardSize, None)
        retR, cornersR = cv.findChessboardCorners(grayR, chessboardSize, None)
    
        #if found, add object points, images points (after refining them)
    
        if retL and retR == True:
    
            objpoints.append(objp)
    
            cornersL = cv.cornerSubPix(grayL, cornersL, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
            imgpointsL.append(cornersL)
    
            cornersR = cv.cornerSubPix(grayR, cornersR, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
            imgpointsR.append(cornersR)
    
            #Draw and display the coorners
    
            cv.drawChessboardCorners(grayL, chessboardSize, cornersL, retL)
            cv.imshow('img left', grayL)
            cv.drawChessboardCorners(grayR, chessboardSize, cornersR, retR)
            cv.imshow('img right', grayR)
            cv.waitKey(1000)
    
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
    
    ####################### CALIIBRATION 
    
    retL, cameraMatrixL, distL, rvecsL, tvecsL = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpointsL, frameSize, None, None)
    heightL, widthL, channelsL = imgL.shape
    newCameraMatrixL, roi_L = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(cameraMatrixL, distL, (widthL, heightL), 1, (widthL, heightL))
    
    retR, cameraMatrixR, distR, rvecsR, tvecsR = cv.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpointsR, frameSize, None, None)
    heightR, widthR, channelsR = imgR.shape
    newCameraMatrixR, roi_R = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(cameraMatrixR, distR, (widthR, heightR), 1, (widthR, heightR))
    
    ############ STEREO VISION CALIBRATION #######
    
    flags = 0
    flags |= cv.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC
    
    #here we fix the intrisic camara matrixes so that only rot, trns, emat and fmat are calculated
    #hence intriscic parameters are the same
    
    criteria_stereo = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
    
    #this step is performed to transformation between the two cameras and calculate essential and fundamental matrix
    
    retStereo, newCameraMatrixL, distL, newCameraMatrixR, distR, rot, trans, essentialMatrix, fundamentalMatrix = cv.stereoCalibrate(objpoints, imgpointsL, imgpointsR, newCameraMatrixL, distL, newCameraMatrixR, distR, grayL.shape[::-1], criteria_stereo, flags)
    
    ########## Stereo Rectification #################################################
    
    rectifyScale= 1
    rectL, rectR, projMatrixL, projMatrixR, Q, roi_L, roi_R = cv.stereoRectify(newCameraMatrixL, distL, newCameraMatrixR, distR, grayL.shape[::-1], rot, trans, rectifyScale,(0,0))
    
    stereoMapL = cv.initUndistortRectifyMap(newCameraMatrixL, distL, rectL, projMatrixL, grayL.shape[::-1], cv.CV_16SC2)
    stereoMapR = cv.initUndistortRectifyMap(newCameraMatrixR, distR, rectR, projMatrixR, grayR.shape[::-1], cv.CV_16SC2)
    
    
    # Criar um dicionário com os dados dos mapas de retificação estéreo
    data = {
        'stereoMapL_x': stereoMapL[0].tolist(),
        'stereoMapL_y': stereoMapL[1].tolist(),
        'stereoMapR_x': stereoMapR[0].tolist(),
        'stereoMapR_y': stereoMapR[1].tolist()
    }
    print(data)
    # Salvar o dicionário no arquivo XML
    cv_file = cv.FileStorage(f'stereoMap.xml', cv.FILE_STORAGE_WRITE)
    cv_file.write('stereomap', data)
    cv_file.release()
```

Comment: dump those big numpy arrays to file using numpy routines, not OpenCV's XML writer stuff. numpy is sure to work. if that still doesn't, it's not the file I/O